# Arduino WiFi shield - Updating firmware

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I am new in arduino and I am trying to update the firmware in my Arduino WiFi shield but I am facing some problems. I did exactly what the instructions said about the update(MacPorts, dfu-programmer, jumper) but when I am trying to run the installation there were some problems that I cannot find out. I haven't change anything in the script, and I really don't know what is going on.
Any help it will be great!!! That's exactly what I get. The problem is in lines 55, 56, 57.

## Arduino WiFi Shield upgrade

Disclaimer: to access to the USB devices correctly, the dfu-programmer needs to be used as root. Run this script as root.

ArduinoWifiShield_upgrade_mac.sh: line 55: cd: /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/firmwares/wifishield/scripts/hardware/tools/avr/bin: No such file or directory

ArduinoWifiShield_upgrade_mac.sh: line 56: ./avr-objcopy: No such file or directory

ArduinoWifiShield_upgrade_mac.sh: line 57: ./avr-objcopy: No such file or directory

****Upgrade WiFi Shield firmware****

Error opening the file.
Something went wrong with creating the memory image.

Done. Remove the J3 jumper and press the RESET button on the shield.
Thank you!

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Do you have the `/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/firmwares/wifishield/scripts/hardware/tools/avr/bin` folder? If not, is there any similar folder in the pack you downloaded for updating the shield?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have this folder but there are full with Unix executable files. I think that the folder that I should use is the /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/firmwares/wifishie‌​ld/scripts where there is the ArduinoWifiShield_upgrade and the ArduinoWifiShield_upgrade_mac. Should I use other folder?

Comment: No.. It's complaining that the command `cd /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/firmwares/wifishield/scripts/hardware/tools/avr/bin` fails saying `No such file or directory`. By the way... It says `Run this script as root`.. So are you running it as root? I don't know MAC but on linux I'd try writing just `sudo ArduinoWifiShield_upgrade_mac.sh` or something similar..

Comment: I am running it as root because I use the sudo command. As about the first error what path should I use? The path of where the script is or where the copied files from the binary file? Another issue is the ./avr-objcopy that I don't know what it is at all..

Comment: Sorry for being late. Anyway it is just trying to launch the executable `avr-objcopy` located in the folder `/Applications/bla bla/avr/bin`. And then it's complaining because he can't find the directory and so he can't launch the program. So first you have to check that the `bla bla/avr/bin` folder exists, then that inside there is an executable file named `avr-objcopy`. If they are there, then probably it's just a matter of permissions... But anyway you should launch the script from its own directory...